# Change font color of text in $scope variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS. I have a scope variable `$scope.TextToUser` which is printed in html to be shown to user on website. In my controller, the code is simple and looks like this;

```
$scope.TextToUser='UserText'
```

On the corresponding html page, the code is just `{{TextToUser}}`.

I tried to turn the text to red by using the following code in the controller;

```
$scope.TextToUser = '<font size="3" color="red"> 'UserText'</font>'
```

Unfortunately, on the html page, the entire string was printed and not `UserText` in red. How can I turn the text red? Simple, straight-forward methods will be preferred.

Comment: What happened to all the earlier answers? Got deleted? They looked promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, following is more proper:

```
app = angular.module('<name of your app>', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('<controller name>', function($scope, $interpolate){
    $scope.Text = 'Test to User In Red';
    $scope.TextToUser = $interpolate('<font size="3" color="red">{{Text}}</font>')($scope);
});
```

Now bind `html`:

```
<span ng-bind-html="TextToUser"></span>
```

You need to include sanitize script. https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular-sanitize.js

Note:- I tried using `$interpolate` but it gives error about `unsafe` stuff without `ngSanitize`.

The working plunk is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMirNw3vqYrYj6jU49Kg?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks. Got worried what happened to your answer. It suddenly disappeared just now. Will try it out. Many thanks again.

Comment: @user768421 was putting up plunk with proper way of doing it.

Comment: Wow. So helpful of you. THanks!!